# cd to a directory by typing its name?

Tags: terminal, bash, folders, command-line

For example if a directory 'blob' exists and I just type 'blob[return]' then the system `cd`s into the blob directory for me.

In Linux (Ubuntu) I can add `shopt -s autocd` to my `.bashrc` file, but on OS X this gives an error: `-bash: shopt: autocd: invalid shell option name`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`autocd` was added in bash 4.0. You can install a newer version of bash with Homebrew and then change the default login shell with `chsh`:

```
brew install bash;echo /usr/local/bin/bash|sudo tee -a /etc/shells;chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash
```

After you open a new login shell (or a tab by default in Terminal or iTerm 2), `echo $BASH_VERSION` should print something like `4.2.45(2)-release`.

Terminal and iTerm 2 open new shells as login shells by default, so bash reads `~/.bash_profile` but not `~/.bashrc`. If you don't source `~/.bashrc` from `~/.bash_profile` or anything, add `shopt -s autocd` to `~/.bash_profile` instead of `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Great answer. Bash 4 is also available in MacPorts:subbing  `sudo port install bash` into your step 1 works as well.

Comment: I did the above.  I ended up with bash 4.2.29 and I made the changes to /etc/shells and did the cssh but no joy

Comment: @MichaelDurrant I edited the answer. `bash -version` would be the first version on $PATH. Did you try `echo $BASH_VERSION`?

Comment: it works if i run the command directly /usr/local/bin/bash - i get v4.2  but how do I make that my default shell for a new window?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Is your terminal application set to open with something like `/usr/bin/login` or `login -fp $USER` in the preferences?

Comment: Accepted plus I added a screenprint of where to change that.

Comment: Although it doesn't work in tmux and it also doesn't show my PS1 (?) prompt with directory and username

Comment: @MichaelDurrant I removed the screenshot from the answer since both Terminal and iTerm 2 should default to opening a login shell. If the default shell is `/usr/bin/local/bash` without `--login`, `.bash_profile` isn't loaded.

Comment: [unaccept] This doesn't work for a new mac I am setting up.

Comment: Tried again to use newer bash but even running /usr/local/bin/bash and then `bash --version `says `3.2.51(1)` after a `brew install bash` saying `4.2.45 already installed`

Comment: If `/bin` is before `/usr/local/bin` on the path, `bash --version` is like `/bin/bash --version`. Try `echo $BASH_VERSION` instead. Did you add `shopt -s autocd` to `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: 2017 ran into this again.  And again got stuck on old version.  @user495470 removed my screeshot which would have really helped me.  I don't care what 'should' happen.  As is this answer leads me stuck every time I rediscover it.

Answer (score 2):

The output of `shopt -p` can be of some help here.  It prints a list of settable options.  Sadly, on Lion, `autocd` is *not* one of them (see excerpt below).

**Edit** [Lauri's answer above](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/55424/23703) has a solution for updating your shell to include `autocd`

```
$ shopt -p
shopt -u cdable_vars
shopt -u cdspell
shopt -u checkhash
shopt -s checkwinsize
shopt -s cmdhist
shopt -u compat31
shopt -u dotglob
shopt -u execfail
shopt -s expand_aliases
shopt -u extdebug
shopt -u extglob
shopt -s extquote
shopt -u failglob
shopt -s force_fignore
shopt -u gnu_errfmt
shopt -u histappend
shopt -u histreedit
shopt -u histverify
shopt -s hostcomplete
shopt -u huponexit
shopt -s interactive_comments
shopt -u lithist
shopt -s login_shell
shopt -u mailwarn
shopt -u no_empty_cmd_completion
shopt -u nocaseglob
shopt -u nocasematch
shopt -u nullglob
shopt -s progcomp
shopt -s promptvars
shopt -u restricted_shell
shopt -u shift_verbose
shopt -s sourcepath
shopt -u xpg_echo
```