# How can I stop sharing Find/Replace fields between apps?

Tags: search, macos

For some baffling reason, Apple thinks that whatever I search for in one app will be the same thing that I want to search for in another app.  This results in my actual search terms being overwritten in (for example) my text editor just because I searched for something on a web page or in iTunes.  Having my carefully-craft regex replaced with "Pink Floyd" is aggravating, to say the least, especially when using a text editor without a search history. The user-interface thinking that led Apple to this decision is beyond my ability to comprehend, but I really would like a way to turn it off.  How can I disable this?

PS: [Why does a find field value in one application show up in a the find field of another application?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/80894/3553) raises a similar question but the answer offered there only applies to the specific scenario of the question, and to BBEdit as an application. I‘m looking for a way to control this behavior in general.

Comment: This is a proper feature of macOS and very much intended behaviour. I *know* it’s been asked a long time ago and resolved really recently (hence I’ve remembered it)) but I can’t find the duplicate.

Comment: Here's a [question and several answers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82770/do-any-os-x-apps-ease-search-and-replace-across-multiple-files) on AskDifferent for somebody who **needs** the functionality you want to abolish. Perhaps you have running one of the apps mentioned in the varied answers? Are you running [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com) by chance?

Comment: @Icon That’s something different, that’s performing a single search across multiple files, not what this question (the macOS feature of replicating search box content cross-app) is asking about.

Comment: @Icon Got the duplicate, take a look to see what this question is asking (asked in 2013, answered this month!)

Comment: @grgarside Nice find!

Comment: @grg the answer in the linked question fixes it for one app (BBEdit), not universally.

Comment: If you think the linked question is not a duplicate (and doesn't answer your question), please **edit** your question to explain why those answers don't solve your specific problem.

Comment: Right now the (only) answer to the linked question *does* explain how to turn this off. Maybe it doesn't work in your setup (or it's difficult to find the right value for `<program>`), but without an edit of your question nobody will be aware of that.

Comment: What does it say that when I ask to turn off a feature that I think is ill-conceived, I'm accused of trying to "abolish" "the functionality" that "somebody... **needs**"? 